# listing all contents of a member in 2 tables (questions, answers)

Tags: php, mysql, select, inner-join

wanted to list all questions and all answers of an individual. 
I do not know if I should use or inner select.

**Tbquestions**
id - member - question - title

**Tbanswers**
id - member - answer - title

need to get only the title of each table

Comment: but I use inner or simple select?

Comment: use simple select. its faster and more importantly is less costly on your database.

Comment: A sample of the data in the tables, and an example of the expected resultset would help to answer your question. Normally, for a JOIN operation, we expect there to be a foreign key relationship between the tables. Normally, we would expect the `id` columns to be the primary key, and not expect those to match. We expect multiple rows for a member in each table, a JOIN on member would give a cross product, every row from Tbquestions matched with every row from Tbanswers, a potentially large resultset with lots of duplicates.

Comment: I want to list the questions asked by the user and the answers he gave

Comment: @Papa Charlie: do you want to do any sort of "match" between the questions and answers, do you want to return a particular answer for each question, or just match every question with every answer? If you want just to combine two lists, then combining two queries with a UNION ALL set operator is the way to go.

Comment: I would get the title of all questions and all answers that someone made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT id,member,'Q' as Type, question as QA FROM Tbquestions
WHERE member='member1'
UNION ALL
SELECT id,member,'A' as Type, answer as QA FROM Tbanswers
WHERE member='member1'
```

Sample Output:

```
id   member   Type   QA
1    Name1    Q      What is it?
3    Name4    Q      Who are you?
1    Name2    A      My name is Name2
4    Name3    A      He is dead, Jim.
```

**EDIT**

Added `Limit` clause for each query to find 5 questions and 10 answers:

```
SELECT id,member,'Q' as Type, question as QA FROM Tbquestions
WHERE member='member1' LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT id,member,'A' as Type, answer as QA FROM Tbanswers
WHERE member='member1' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @r3wt: Waste of db resources? Thats what union all is used for.

Comment: +1. For a query like this, I would normally include a discriminator column, the first SELECT returning `'Q' AS src`, the second query returning an `'A'`, so we know which source a row came from.

Comment: @PapaCharlie: if you only need to return the "title" from each table, you could replace the references to `id`, `member`, and `question`/`answer` with just `title`. (As I noted in an earlier comment, I typically will include a discriminator column (literal value) which differs in each query, so I can tell which source query returned the row. That may not be important to you; it's not required, but it can be useful in some cases.

Comment: My output: `Array
    [0] => Array
            [id] => 1
            [member] => 1
            [type] => Q
            [qa] => What is it?

    [1] => Array
            [id] => 2
            [member] => 1
            [type] => Q
            [qa] => Who are you?

    [2] => Array
            [id] => 1
            [member] => 1
            [type] => A
            [qa] => My name is Name2

    [3] => Array
            [id] => 2
            [member] => 1
            [type] => A
            [qa] => He is dead, Jim.
` I use the type tag for the type of information. thanks for the help

Comment: this example is functioning correctly, but it certainly will have to do a pagination on that table ... `(SELECT...)UNION ALL(SELECT...) LIMIT x,x ` its work?

Comment: You want to `limit` the answer to x questions and y answers? Then add the limit clause too.

Comment: i don't see an 'order by' clause - how did you enforce that ordering?

Comment: @PapaCharlie: Added the `limit` clause to my answer.

Comment: @RyanVincent: The order will be like, questions first and then answers (shown in the sample output). If we want to order by some other column, we can do `SELECT * FROM (full query) ORDER BY col_name`, my friend.

Comment: Your sample output before was by id and then 'Q', 'A'. Now it is as you say. Was trying to point out that the order of the rows returned is not certain unless an 'order by' is used.

Comment: but in paging would not be the total limit encompassing 2 selects?

Comment: @RyanVincent: Yes, just edited it. Thanks for pointing it out, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Join should be done if there is relationship between question and the corresponding answer.
Since the tables are related by member id , i don't think join should be used. Instead do simple select and combine resultset from both tables using UNION ALL

Comment: as the response of Raging Bull?

Comment: Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: @r3wt: Waste of db resources? Thats what union all is used for.

Comment: yeah that's what the book tells you Raging bull.i could be totally wrong but its my opinion that you should only use simple queries, and use php to do the legwork from there.

Comment: @mhasan: Well, you don't deserve a -1. :-)

Comment: i'm sorry mhasan. it won't let me remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $mysqli;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title from Tbquestions WHERE member = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$member);
if($stmt->execute()){
$stmt->bind_result($questions);
$stmt->close();
}
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title from Tbanswers WHERE member = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$member);
if($stmt->execute()){
$stmt->bind_result($answers);
$stmt->close();
}
$allposts = array_merge($questions, $answers);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($allposts, false);
```

Comment: We're sorry, but this is somewhat obvious ... my doubt is to make an appointment and not two

Comment: no problem, just the case is to use just a query to resolve the problem :)